# We get disconnected from the Internet every time we switch user

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

My computer is connected to the router via a USB wireless card (TP-LINK WN7200ND). It runs Windows XP and we use Fast User Switching. It seems that every time a user uses the Internet, the others get disconnected. To reconnect, one has to disconnect the wireless card and connect it again.

This is annoying. What can I do?

Comment: What make and model is the router? And if it's connected to a modem by Ethernet, make *sure* the modem is connected to the Internet/WAN port on the router!

Comment: The router is Linksys WRT54GL. And yes, the modem is connected to the Internet port.

Comment: 100% check that. The most common cause of this problem is connecting the modem to a LAN port by mistake. The second most common is setting the router to act as a bridge rather than a router. (So check the router's configuration while you're at it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some ideas from the web about this.

**RAS REG Hack:** .  Hack the registry so ras stays connected between users, ?? weird I thought ras was all about the Dial-Up but a few wireless users said it worked? it cannot hurt to try. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/158909

**Fast User Switching** The use of, or Not Fast user switching, the first thing I searched for. Fast user switching keeps the other users programs going on the computer, causes its own problems. Fast user switching seems to ME to be the best method to try and "keep things going" as that is what it does.  On the other hand Stopping things,  resetting , could reset it and get it going again without physical removal.

**What Software?** The use of or Not the built in wireless zero configuration , microsofts OWN wireless software, which runs as a service. Vrses using some software that might disconnect between users (because it is not a service). What software is being used for the wireless adapter device?

http://forums.techarena.in/networking-security/1371294.htm

I percieve that 2 of these items are like the usual combination lock :-) and you would have to have at least 2 of 3 in the correct configuration before you are done.  testing different ways , might be needed.

So that covered web users attempts to keep it connected. I assume if you could somehow achieve keeping it connected you might not have the connection problem?  If it would hardware reset fully you might not have the device problem.

---

Even with a device problem, you could potentially script the removal of the device, and achieve re-connection.  If the  attempts to keep it connected  do not keep it connected, you still are pulling the card out??? after about 1000 disconnections whatever port the card is in might get damaged.

So, for the device problem, we have a few possibilities. Purposfully setting the device TO shut off  power in it's device settings power managment. the Idea here being to encourage a reset , even at log-off/in.  Or the opposite.

Then you can test disabling the device in Device manager, then re-enabling it, instead of pulling the device physically.  If it is possible to disable it in the device manager, it would be possible to kick it out at log-off, and kick it back in a log-in, in software using scripts.  That should get a reset, and a reset should get a re-connection.

Speaking of "device" it would not hurt to know all the "advanced" options that are available in the network devices properties/advanced, just in case something there is part of the combination lock :-)  I doubt it, but it does not hurt to look.

I cant believe that multi-users would put up with this kind of thing, and XP used simple methods, so I think there is at least hope.

This post assumes  things, because the text of the questioner could have 2 meanings.  I assumed Switching users on a SINGLE XP computer, and not other computers involved also getting the routers wireless.

Comment: Nothing there, unfortunately. RAS didn't help, and we already use Fast User Switching.

Comment: And yes, I use Windows' zeroconf.

Comment: My bad. I was using both zeroconf AND TP-link's utility!

Answer (score 0):

XP does not contain an in-built way to reliably keep the wireless connection between user sessions.  It's usually up to the wireless adapter's connection manager software to provide this feature (Intel refers to it as "Pre-Logon" and "Single Sign On" in their Wireless ProSet utility, for example).

Unfortunately many vendors don't offer this level of configurability, if they even provide a management utility (many just rely on Windows' in-built wireless manager).

Judging by a quick look at [TP-Link's download section for that model](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-WN7200ND#down), it would appear they do not offer an additional management software.

Another thing to ensure is that you all have the same preferred networks setup.  If one login doesn't have a preferred network, or has another network set as preferred it may attempt to connect to that when they are logged in (after first disconnecting existing connections).